# Parallel Processing in Image Categorization <Can't get attribute 'imcat' on <module 'main' (built-in)>

Tags: python, image-processing, parallel-processing, neural-network, computer-vision

I am attempting to implement parallel processing on a computer vision project I am working on for my dissertation.  I have hundreds of thousands of images to analyze, and I'm hoping that parallel processing will allow me to analyze multiple images at the same time to reduce the overall amount of time this will take.  Here is my initial attempt.

```
from deepface import DeepFace
import os
import pandas as pd
from time import process_time
import multiprocessing as mp

data = []
for file in sorted(os.listdir("C:\\Dissertation\\UWD Test")):
    data.append((file))
```

Here, data is just a list of filenames in a small sample folder of about 50 images.

```
def imcat(imname):
    try:
        obj = DeepFace.analyze(img_path = imname, actions = ['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])
        filename = imname
        age = (list(obj.values())[0])
        sex = (list(obj.values())[1])
        race = (list(obj.values())[3])
        emotion = (list(obj.values())[5])
        catdict = {}
        for variable in ['filename', 'age', 'sex', 'race', 'emotion']:
            catdict[variable] = eval(variable)
        return catdict
    except:
        pass
```

I am trying to use the DeepFace architecture to retrieve attributes for each individual image and to save them in a dictionary, catdict.  The function returns the dictionary.

```
pool = mp.Pool(8)

templist = []
t1_start = process_time()
pool = mp.Pool(processes = 8)
results = [pool.apply(imcat, args=(data[i])) for i in range(0, len(data))]
templist.append(results)
t1_stop = process_time()
print("Elapsed time:", t1_stop, t1_start) 
   
print("Elapsed time during the whole program in seconds:",
                                         t1_stop-t1_start)
```

Here I am attempting to use the defined function imcat to analyze each filename in the list "data", save that analysis to a dictionary catdict, and append the dictionary for each image to the list "templist".

Unfortunately I receive the following error.

> Can't get attribute 'imcat' on <module '**main**' (built-in)>

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I am relatively new to python, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There may be a few things at play here.

1. You should use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` construct for multiprocessing code. You can find details in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
2. The error tries to tell you that it can't find `imcat` in the `main` module (which is probably the current running module, where your code resides). You may have issues if running from a Jupyter notebook due to point 1.
3. If errors persist, you could try putting this function in another module and importing it before using it.